# Algorithm: find minimum space spanning points defined only by their separations

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array, geometry, computational-geometry, metrics

I have a collection of points in some N-dimensional space, where all I know is the distances between them. Let's say it's an unordered collection of structs like the following:

```
struct {
    int first;         // Just some identifier that uniquely specifies a point
    int second;        // No importance to which point is first or second
    float separation;  // The distance between the first and second points -- always positive
};
```

Of course the algorithm doesn't have to be C code. I just wrote the struct in this style to make the problem clear. It rather upsets me that the struct spoils the symmetry between the two end-points, but fixing this just makes things more complicated.

Let's say that the separations are defined by the Pythagorean distance between them, and the space is Euclidean. Let's also specify that the separations are internally consistent. For example, given separations AB, BC and AC, we know that AB + BC >= AC.

I want an algorithm that finds the minimal dimensional space that can contain all the points. Within this algorithm, we can assume that separations that deviate from that defined by the space by less than some specified tolerance can be ignored.

Does anyone know an algorithm that does this? So far, I've only been able to think up non-polynominal algorithms. Can anybody improve on that, or at least make something that is clean and extensible?

Why is this interesting? In Physics there are some low-level theories such as String Theory or Quantum Loop Gravity that do not obviously predict our three dimensional world. This algorithm could be part of a project to find how a 3d world can be emergent.

Comment: Are you looking for a manifolds or a subspaces only?

Comment: @collideorscape in 2D, can we say that "space" is actually a "surface"?

Comment: @colideorscape also, if I understood well you only have the reference to point ? Nothing about coordinates? Is that correct?

Comment: To answer some of these points. Yes, it can be thought of a manifold. It is not necessarily a subspace, as there is no superspace. There is no time coordinate -- this is a static problem, so mechanisms are irrelevant. You can think of it as the vertices of a rigid body if you like, though it is just points in some space. I like the idea of using simplices to enumerate the space. (This is a lot of simplices -- hence the non-polynominal aspect.) There are no coordinates, though it may make sense to invent some on the way to a solution. Points are only defined by a unique integer -- nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everybody who posted ideas here. I now have an answer to my own question. It's not great, in that it executes O(n^3) but at least it's polynomial. Roughly, it works like this:

1. Represent the problem as a symmetric matrix with zero diagonal -- representing the distances between any two points. This is equivalent to the representation using structs, but much easier to work with.
2. Assume the ordering of the points implied by the matrix (first column/row = first point) is sensible. (It may be worth pivoting to find a better ordering, but that is todo.)
3. Now create a rectangular coordinate system to fit the points, starting with the first point, which WLOG we take to be the origin.
4. Second point defines the x axis
5. For each subsequent point, we calculate its coordinates one at a time, starting with the x axis. We know the distance from the origin and the distance from point 2. This allows us to calculate the x coordinate, as we end up with two simultaneous equations x^2 + y^2 + ... = s1^2 and (x - x2)^2 + y^2 + ... = s2^2, which allows us to calculate x easily from x2, the x coordinate of point 2, and the distances from points 1 and 2, s1 and s2.
6. Each new coordinate can be calculated easily, because the matrix of coordinates calculated so far is triangular -- there is only one unknown each time.
7. The last coordinate for each point is on a new axis -- a dimension that has not yet been used. Calculate its coordinate using Pythagoras on the distance from the origin, as we know all the other coordinates.
8. It is possible that the coordinate on the new axis will come out imaginary -- a general set of distances cannot always be represented by a coordinate system of any number of dimensions -- at least not with real numbers. If this is the case, I error.
9. Keep going in this way for each new point, building up a vector of coordinate vectors for each point. In general, this is triangular, but there may be cases where the final coordinate we calculate is near enough to zero that we consider the point's position to be represented by the existing dimensions. I store the coordinates anyway, but keep the number of dimensions the same as the previous point. I also skip these points, as they are not needed for calculating further points (see step 10).
10. Finally, we have represented all points such that the distances are consistent.
11. As a final check, I validate that the distances match for all points, including those skipped in step 9.
12. The number of dimensions needed is the number used for the last point.

If anyone is interested in an implementation of this (in Haskell), it is on my GitHub page at https://github.com/MarcusRainbow/EmergentDimensions/coords.hs.